# Google Endpoints with Laravel API project

Tags: laravel, api, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an API developed with Laravel.
Is it generally possible to use Google Endpoints?
I read that you need a special YAML file. Does anyone know of a tutorial that describes this?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, **YES** it is possible to use Google Endpoints as long as you are authorized to use them via the API keys/Password grant/Whatever authorization you specify on Google API Console. You don't need any special `YAML` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put Endpoints proxy in front of your API, you need to deploy a description of the shape of the API to the system. It is a yaml file following the OpenAPI 2.0 specification.

I've found a tool to generate OpenAPI spec from Laravel code on Github (https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger) Maybe it could be helpful for your use case.